# How to dynamically set selected value to a optionCollections in Struts

Tags: java, default, struts1

I have a list of Customer, and a list of Country from database. 
Then render Country list to a countryCombobox with OptionCollections:

```
    <html:select property="countryCode" name="countries">
        <html:optionsCollection name="Cuountry" value="countryCode" label="countryName" />
    </html:select>
```

I want to display the value of countryCombobox respectively to the chosen Customer(from the Customer list page).
Example:
if Customer A belong to Country1, then countryCombobox will display Country1, and so on

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-html-select-tag-example-1.html) gives an example that is almost exactly what you need.

If this is not what you are facing, please elaborate in you question and add some more code.